# connection string to a SQL Server cluster

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, cluster-computing

Could anyone point me or tell me how to write connection string to a SQL Server cluster instance?

I want to establish trusted connection to a database (initial catalog) of the specific instance of a SQL Server cluster. I find for quite some time but can not find official answer from Google.

I am asking for the connection string for C# ADO.Net code.

I know how to write connection string to a normal one-machine non-cluster SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 4):

The server name is the virtual server name.

Example:

- You have Physical `pserver1`, `pserver2`
- These together make cluster `cserver` 
  -This hosts virtual servers `vserv1` (and perhaps, see below) `vserv2`

So, it's `vserv1\instancename` or `vserv1`. you don't use physical server names

Edit, based on number of possible names for virtual servers:

The cluster may be active/passive /A/P) or active/active (A/A)

- In A/P, only one virtual server is hosted and the standby node is not actively used.
- In A/A, there are 2 virtual servers and normally each node hosts one. Each node is standby for the other.

Comment: Confused -- "hosts virtual servers vserv1 (and perhaps) vserv2", do you mean the cluster has two virtual server name, vserv1 and vserv2? Or it is a typo?

Comment: what is the connection string format of SQL cluster non-default instance?

Comment: vserv1\instancename (or vserv2\instancenamein A/A scenarios

Answer (score 3):

The connection string is written in the usual way; but in clustering you have 3 (or more) addresses: one for each node which constitues the cluster and one for the cluster.
E.g.: we have two node with addresses 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.20: if you write down one of this numbers as the DataSource in the connection string, you'll gain access to that physical instance. But if you want to access the cluster (virtual) Sql Server instance, you'll have to use the cluster's address (e.g.: 192.168.0.230) as the DataSource.
Of course, you can also use the machines' names instead of the IP addresses, provided you are in the same domain as the cluster.

Comment: Using machine names does not depend on being in the same domain, only on the names being exposed in DNS. And having a rational DNS configuration: this might be a problem in some organisation :-(.

Comment: You're right; i was focusing on the connection string and missed this point, sorry.

Comment: @Turro, 1. what is the connection string format of SQL cluster non-default instance? 2. For a SQL cluster, do we allow to connect by machine name to access individual machine instead of virtual server name? Does such access corrupt data mirroring between two virtual nodes?

Comment: @Richard, what is the problem do you mean?

Comment: @George2: 1) the connection string is always the same, you just have to specify in the DataSource=xxx the name of the instance you want to access; e.g.: Password=pwd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=THENAMEORTHEIPADDRESSOFTHEINSTANCE;

Comment: @George2: 2) I would not use the individual instances; actually I don't know if you run the risk of corrupting the data, but for sure you loose the benefit of the cluster. That is, if the "master" instance is down (for whatever reason) and you are accessing the default cluster, your connection will trasparently switch to the other (which has becoma active) without any intervention. But if you are accessing the individual instance and this is down, your application will not be able to access it; is it worth to have a cluster and not to use it? Maybe, but *I* wouldn't do that

Comment: @George2: I'm just guessing Richard thoughts, but perhaps he referred to the fact that some organizations could lack the skills to mantain a DNS configuration. Or at least, this has been the case for some of my custmers in the past...

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented anywhere that I could find, but I had to use the name of the availability group listener on the cluster. For example:

```
data-source=tcp:AG1-Listener
```

Literally, this is documented nowhere. I got lucky and found a connection string to a cluster on a blog somewhere and figured it out from there.

Comment: It is now documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/273673

explains why a timeout should be specified on the connection. An extract is below.

If a SQL Server server is failed over by the cluster admin, TCP reset packets are not sent. If the SQL Server process is terminated by the operating system (by Kill.exe), the reset packets are sent.

This may affect the client application if the application does not specify a query timeout parameter or a query timeout of zero (0).

If the application does not have a query timeout value then open connections will be left in the ESTABLISHED state after a failover occurs. The fact that the open connections are not closed and that no further TCP packets are sent from those connections indicates that those connections are completely idle. Because the failover did not send any TCP reset packets to the client application, those open connections wait for the query results indefinitely (assuming an infinite query timeout), and potentially cause the connection to stop responding (hang).