# connection string of ADO.Net of SQL Server

Tags: sql, string, ado.net, connection, cluster-computing

I am confused about the connection string format of ADO.Net when connect to a non-default instance of SQL Cluster. I did search but find various samples, could anyone let me know what is the correct format please (if I know the virtual server name and instance name)? I am using trusted connection.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServerName\InstanceName ?  Use double \ when handling strings in C#

Comment: I did not find any official documents covering the connection string format for SQL cluster non-default instance. Do you have any referred documents?

Comment: I have passed MCTS on Sql Server, so I had to learn ;-), dont remeber exactly when I learned it. I thinh MSDN has some interesting section regarding sql server connnection strings, but I usually takes me some time to find it. Someone posted good reference to web site about connection strings here

Comment: Thanks all the same, appreciated if you could post your findings when you find samples for connection string format of SQL cluster non-default instance. I also searched in MSDN, but finding nothing.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx
and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808

Comment: @smok1, I want to confirm with you that for non-default instance, the connection string to SQL Cluster should be -- virtualservername\instancename, and connection string to default instance should be virtualservername.

Comment: @George2: yes, this is how it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, smok1!

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ - great site for making DB connection strings.

Comment: No samples for connection string format for SQL cluster non-default instance. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The following web site gives many different connection strings for you. The following should work I believe:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#1

This is also a duplicate of [connection string to a SQL Server cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751634/connection-string-to-a-sql-server-cluster)

Comment: I did not find official answer from the links you provided. :-)

Comment: To quote: "Use serverName\instanceName as Data Source"

Comment: I want to confirm with you that for non-default instance, the connection string to SQL Cluster should be -- virtualservername\instancename, and connection string to default instance should be virtualservername?

Comment: Can't you just try it and see if it works - surely that would be quicker than waiting for my reply. I connect to a machine on a cluster here with that format so it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to it using visual studio the connection properties should give you the connectionstring vs.net uses. Using that connectionstring might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick & easy way to try different connection strings, I suggest [DatabaseTester](http://www.sql-reports.net/2011/03/how-to-easily-test-your-adonet-connections.html) (disclaimer - I wrote it). It's free and a very easy way to test. And I agree with the other posts above, for figuring out connections strings [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) is your best friend.