# JDBC connect string for SQL Server cluster

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, cluster-computing

I need to setup a JDBC connection string to SQL Server.
This question is similar to the the [C# ADO.Net connection question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751634/connection-string-to-a-sql-server-cluster). This one is specific to JDBC connection strings.

The usual format for the JDBC string is "jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port}".
Now, for a SQL server cluster I have a cluster name vvv\iii ({virtual server}{instance name}).

There's no problem setting up an ODBC connection through the "New Data Source to SQL Server" wizard when using the vvv\iii string as the server name. However it seems the JDBC connection string requires a specific host and port.

Is there a way to make a JDBC connect string to a SQL Server cluster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it turns out that you can use the "instanceName" property within the JDBC string, as documented on the [Microsoft Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(SQL.90).aspx) in section "Named and Multiple SQL Server Instances". What worked in my case was the following string for virtual server vvv and database instance name iii:

"jdbc:sqlserver://vvv;instanceName=iii"

Comment: I dislike to accept my own answer but it's the best one so far ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When using a SQL Server named instance in a cluster or stand alone environment each SQL Server instance is dynamically assigned a port number on startup. The SQL Server Browser server handles requests to each instance because each server restart could change the port number used by each instance. The first instance to start on a server reboot gets assigned 1433 but there is no guarantee if you have 2 instances that one of them will always get 1433. There are several veriables that affect the startup and recovery time it takes for an instance to start. This can change each time.

That being sad... when connecting to a named instance the jdbc connection string should look like this:
jdbc:sqlserver://server_name/db_name;instance=instance_name

rather than this
jdbc:sqlserver://server_name:1433/db_name;instance=instance_name

note that the default database "/db_name" is optional. If exclued the connection will use the default database assigned to the SQL Server login.

Answer (score 0):

The cluster resource has a host name and a listening port. Use j`dbc:sqlserver://{virtualserver}:1433` (or the appropriate listening port if not listening on the default one).

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment  [Mark Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2825150/mark-stewart)'s remark, but the reputation is lacking. [My source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) doesn't mention /db_name and I can't get it to work either. Maybe another case of [confused instance names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310536/how-to-make-java-work-with-sql-server/8049711#8049711)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you leave the port definition off as the cluster determine this for you.

So my datasource definition looks like:

`jdbc:sqlserver://sqlcluster_hostname\instancename;DATABASENAME=databasename;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;SelectMethod=direct`

I ran into this issue while trying to setup a Railo datasource to connect to MSSQL cluster.

Slightly off topic ... The standard Railo datasource MSSQL driver option sets the port to "-1" if you leave the port field empty however if you set it to "0" then it removes the port definition altogether and then everything works.  But the best way is to choose 'Other - JDBC Driver' to define the JDBC connection string in full as above.