# SessionFactory - one factory for multiple databases

Tags: nhibernate, sessionfactory

We have a situation where we have multiple databases with identical schema, but different data in each.  We're creating a single session factory to handle this.

The problem is that we don't know which database we'll connect to until runtime, when we can provide that.  But on startup to get the factory build, we need to connect to a database with that schema.  We currently do this by creating the schema in an known location and using that, but we'd like to remove that requirement.

I haven't been able to find a way to create the session factory without specifying a connection. We don't expect to be able to use the OpenSession method with no parameters, and that's ok.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Why not just provide the connection details at runtime in the `Configuration` object rather than at compile-time in your configuration file?

Comment: Why you do that ? I'm curious...

Comment: @Kent:  Well we do, the problem is the point at which we build the factory (on startup) we don't actually need a connection, but build it so that the user isn't waiting when they get to the point that does actually open the connection.

Comment: @Pierre:  Scalability and uptime.  The same data ends up in multiple places, but a higher traffic customer may get their own server while lower traffic ones can share, and one system going down doesn't take everyone down.

Comment: You don't have to have 2 connection strings if you have a database cluster with replication. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751634/connection-string-to-a-sql-server-cluster

Comment: @anonymized:  I realized I mispoke in my comments; it's not the same data, but the same schema.  So we split our larger customers data across multiple databases (and servers), but the data is more or less unique in each database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came up with was to create a class which manages this for us.  The class can use some information in the method call to do some routing logic to figure out where the database is, and then call OpenSession passing the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Either implement your own `IConnectionProvider` or pass your own connection to `ISessionFactory.OpenSession(IDbConnection)` (but read the method's comments about connection tracking)

Comment: Care to provide us with an example?

Comment: Mauricio, thanks, I'll check into that.  I had thought about your latter suggestion, but it wasn't clear from my research if NHibernate would close the connection or if we would take on the responsibility.  I'll read up on the IConnectionProvider, it looks like that might be closer to what we need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the great NuGet package from brady gaster for this. I made my own implementation from his NHQS package and it works very well.

You can find it here:

http://www.bradygaster.com/Tags/nhqs

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this and thought Id add my solution for future readers which is basically what Mauricio Scheffer has suggested which encapsulates the 'switching' of CS and provides single point of management (I like this better than having to pass into each session call, less to 'miss' and go wrong).

I obtain the connecitonstring during authentication of the client and set on the context then, using the following IConnectinProvider implementation, set that value for the CS whenever a session is opened:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides ability to switch connection strings of an NHibernate Session Factory (use same factory for multiple, dynamically specified, database connections)
/// </summary>
public class DynamicDriverConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider, IConnectionProvider
{
    protected override string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            var cxnObj = IsWebContext ?
                HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestConnectionString"]: 
                System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.GetData("RequestConnectionString");

            if (cxnObj != null)
                return cxnObj.ToString();
            //catch on app startup when there is not request connection string yet set
            return base.ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsWebContext
    {
        get { return (HttpContext.Current != null); }
    }
}
```

Then wire it in during NHConfig:

```
var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                            .Provider<DynamicDriverConnectionProvider>() //Like so
```